# Java 11 issue with Luna Provider

Tags: java

I am new to Java world and need some help....

My deployment environment is Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

I have a Java program which runs perfectly fine when compiled with Java 8 and I am able to successfully run the Luna security provider end point.

But when I compile it with Java 11 and deploy it in Pivotal Cloud Foundry it gives below error:

```
  2020-12-17T14:33:48.67-0500 [RTR/1] OUT 
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT zero block
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-12-17 19:35:27.441 ERROR 22 --- [io-8080-exec-10] com.example.luna.LunaController          : Exception: {}
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.safenetinc.luna.provider.LunaProvider
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.example.luna.LunaController.testLuna(LunaController.java:46) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:4.0.FR]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.10.RELEASE.jar:5.2.10.RELEASE]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.cloudfoundry.router.ClientCertificateMapper.doFilter(ClientCertificateMapper.java:79) ~[client_certificate_mapper-1.11.0_RELEASE.jar:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.39.jar:9.0.39]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [RTR/1] OUT test-luna-service11.apps-gt1-lab.nam.nsroot.net - [2020-12-17T19:35:27.435180932Z] "GET /test-luna HTTP/1.1" 500 0 7 "-" "curl/7.29.0" "192.168.11.21:45084" "10.255.82.9:61001" x_forwarded_for:"199.67.131.150, 192.168.11.21" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"e0834a37-edfc-4da9-4264-3c3ee434974d" response_time:0.008394 gorouter_time:0.000172 app_id:"0dfb2dde-a7c2-48a0-9567-c7b9233ad890" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"56770bc4f5b3e38f" x_b3_spanid:"56770bc4f5b3e38f" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"56770bc4f5b3e38f-56770bc4f5b3e38f"
   2020-12-17T14:35:27.44-0500 [RTR/1] OUT
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends which buildpack you are using. By default PCF Java buildpacks uses Java 8 with latest version (4.35) as well.. Please refer https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/

You need to use below environment variable to use Java 11..

```
JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE:{ jre: { version: 11.+ } }
```

Comment: Where exactly this information need to go ? in Manifest file or somewhere else ?

Comment: You can pass via mainfest file or using below command:  cf set-env JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE { jre: { version: 11.+ } }

Comment: Issue still stays the same, and it gives error of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Do you see if Java11 being picked up in the logs?

Comment: Yes, buildpack that is picked up is Java 11 only.